# create a calendar reminder in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter. Recently I am doing an app whose main function is add reminders to the Calendar. I am now using the "device_calendar" package to add events into the Calendar app, the problem is that I can create an event but I just can't create a reminder to the event. For example, I created an event at 4:30 p.m., I can only see it in the Calendar App, it won't remind me when it actually comes to 4:30 p.m., which causes a lot of inconvenience.
Can someone tell me how to add reminders using "device_calendar" package, or just tell me some methods about adding events and reminders into the Calendar App with flutter.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide some code that you did so someone can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can handle with [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Schedule localnotification:

```
var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
        new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(seconds: 5));
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails('your other channel id',
        'your other channel name', 'your other channel description');
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new IOSNotificationDetails();
NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
    0,
    'scheduled title',
    'scheduled body',
    scheduledNotificationDateTime,
    platformChannelSpecifics);
```

Comment: how do you specify the period of the reminder? Let's say that I want to create a reminder of my birthday for the next 5 years

Comment: Oh I guess there is no year check in this package you can have a look at `zonedSchedue`method in this package but there can be multiple notifications because there is no month and year check

Answer (score 0):

But Flutter_Local_Notification fails to remaind after when device is rebooted.
May be you can set remainder in google calender in the user's account.